# Specific filtering of a many to many relationship

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to construct a query on three tables representing a many-to-many relationship:

- users
- groups
- user_groups

I need to query for users that are a member of a defined array of groups but if they are a member of any other groups then don't include them in the results.

So I want users that are ONLY in "groupA", "groupD" and "groupZ" but if they were a member of "groupB" then don't return them in the query results.

I know this part:

```
SELECT user.name
FROM user
JOIN user_groups on user_groups.user_id = user.id
JOIN groups on user_groups.group_id = group.id
```

But I don't know how to write the query to return the exact results I want. I should mention that the target DB is an oracle database if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Assume `groups.name` is the column identifying the group.

```
SELECT user.name
FROM user
JOIN user_groups on user_groups.user_id = user.id
JOIN groups on user_groups.group_id = group.id
WHERE groups.name in ("GroupA", "GroupD", "GroupZ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filters in `having` to check for user presence in specific groups.

```
SELECT user.name
FROM user
JOIN user_groups on user_groups.user_id = user.id
JOIN groups on user_groups.group_id = group.id
GROUP BY user.name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN user_groups.group_id='groupB' THEN user_groups.group_id END) = 0
AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN user_groups.group_id IN ('groupA','groupD','groupZ') THEN user_groups.group_id END) = 3
```

Comment: I read the requirement differently - the user must be in one, two, or all three of groups A, D and Z (not necessarily in all three). That simplifies the query, of course.

Comment: @mathguy ..you may be right..i am waiting for op's clarification as the question isn't totally clear.

Answer (score 0):

Its rather ugly, but I'd go with,,,,

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT user_id
  FROM user_groups
  GROUP BY user_id
  HAVING 
   3=SUM (DECODE(group_id, 'GroupA', 1, 'GroupB', 1, 'GroupC', 1, 0))
  AND
   0=SUM (DECODE(group_id, 'GroupA', 0, 'GroupB', 0, 'GroupC', 0, 1))
  )
```